# Live cd and usb install failure blank screen when trying to install on an HP Pavilion dv6

Tags: installation, hp

I recently bought a new computer, and have been trying to install linux on it, 11.10 x64.
It is a HP pavilion dv6-6117dx.

- 2.4GHz/1.5GHz VISION A8 Technology from AMD with AMD Quad-Core A8-3500M Accelerated Processor
- AMD Radeon HD 6620G Discrete-Class Graphics

I am pretty sure i picked a unsupported graphics card or something. I have tried booting from usb as well, but the screen becomes blank after rebooting.

Answer (score 2):

From this post on the Ubuntu Forums

http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11503128&postcount=9

Use `radeon.modeset=0` as a boot option

then install the ati driver

First add the Canonical Partners repository

[image: Partner]

Then

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh 
sudo rm /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx* 
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-'uname -r'
sudo apt-get install fglrx
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo reboot
```

> The second through fourth commands may get a file nor found... Thats okay. Ensuring fragments are not there.

You may need these commands (I am not sure)

```
sudo echo options radeon modeset=0 > /etc/modprobe.d/radeon-kms.conf
sudo update-initramfs -u
```